# Python code to get the (speaker)Audio of zoom app

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, zoom-sdk

I am trying to implement machine learning on the audio's received from zoom meeting. The sounds that are received at output of Speaker should get into a .wav file file or in a variable.
I would like to receive python code for doing this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your operating system you have you will have to set this up differently.

1. Need to create a virtual microphone
2. Set that virtual microphone as the speaker for zoom
3. Point pyaudio to grab that virtual microphone as an input device.
4. Grab data from the stream, parse and feed it into your ML.

I have used virtual microphones for zoom so I can control video and audio through my webcam rather than screenshare. One good virtual microphone that works on windows is "Voicemeeter".

Comment: So can you give any particular piece of code to create the object of virtual microphone on python script and then link it to the particular app . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I made a virtual output (pyaudio) but that index of virtual output when passed to pyaudio doesnot work

Comment: If you are using Voicemeeter then there are two virtual devices. One is a named "Voicemeeter Input" and the other is "Voicemeeter Output". You need to set as a speaker in zoom the one labeled "Voicemeeter Output" then in pyaudio grab the one named "Voicemeeter Input". However pyaudio only supports devices using the MME api. You'll need to select the MME version of the "Voicemeeter Output" in the "Voicemeeter" app. I can't build pyaudio for some reason so I can't run a test at the moment.

Comment: There are some issues with channels by the way it is not able to resolve it and get to voice meter port by index. However i have marked your answer correct and thanks a lot for your time :)